# Extracting zip files using python

Tags: python, zip, extract

I'm trying to get all zip files in a specific directory name "downloaded" and to extract all of their content to a directory named "extracted".

I don't know why, after I'm iterating only existing files name, I get an error that there is no such file...

```
allFilesList = os.listdir(os.getcwd()+"/downloaded")
print allFilesList #verify - correct expected list
from zipfile import ZipFile
os.chdir(os.getcwd()+"/extracted/")
print os.getcwd() #verify - correct expected dir

for fileName in allFilesList: 
    print fileName
    with ZipFile(fileName, 'r') as zipFileObject:
        if os.path.exists(fileName):
            print "Skipping extracting " + fileName
            continue
        zipFileObject.extractall(pwd='hello')                   
        print "Saving extracted file to extracted/",fileName
print "all files has been successfully extracted"
```

Error message:

```
File "program.py", line 77, in <module>
with ZipFile(fileName, 'r') as zipFileObject:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 779, in __init__
    self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'zipFile1.zip'
```

Comment: Your program doesn't seem 77 lines long, so can you turn this into a true [mcve] and then show the error that generates instead?

Comment: it show the same error for the same line - "with ZipFile(fileName, 'r') as zipFileObject:"

Comment: the rest of the code works great, the problem starts after the second print in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the list of filenames from one directory, then changing to another, and trying to extract the files from that directory that likely don't exist:

```
allFilesList = os.listdir(os.getcwd()+"/downloaded")
# ...
os.chdir(os.getcwd()+"/extracted/")
# ...
    with ZipFile(fileName, 'r') as zipFileObject:
```

If you change that file `ZipFile` command to something like this:

```
    with ZipFile(os.path.join("..", "downloaded", fileName), 'r') as zipFileObject:
```

You should be able to open the file in the directory you found it in.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I knew it's related to the path, and your answer helped me to identify the problem's location.